# Assertion Failure iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton

I am using [Vurig-Calendar](https://github.com/tjeerdintveen/Vurig-Calendar) in iOS app.When navigating from a uibutton action to a `viewController` that will show up calendar View I am getting the following error.

```
 Assertion failed: (7 == hexString.length || 4 == hexString.length), function +[UIColor(HexColorAddition) colorWithHexString:alpha:], file /Users/st/Desktop/Developer/THome/THome/HexColor.m, line 33.
```

And the app shows `signal SIGABRT` at this line.

```
// check for string length
assert(7 == hexString.length || 4 == hexString.length);
```

Now I am also using `Hexcolor` library in the app, but there is no connection in navigating and `HexColor` .

How I am navigating is as below on a UIButton Action.

```
CalendarViewController *calVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"CalendarViewController"];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:calVC animated:YES];
```

What may be causing this error?

Comment: Is `HexColor.m` in your source tree (i.e. is it your code)?

Comment: Well it's being misused in some way.  It expects a string of 4 or 7 characters and must be getting something other than that.  In the debugger examine the stack when it asserts, in order to see where the error is.